# Array of foreign keys in Ecto (Phoenix)

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I'm a beginner in web dev so excuse my lack of knowledge.

I have a `Teacher` and a `Student` Ecto schema. They are supposed to be linked via another schema called `Class` by following these rules:

1. Each class has only one teacher, and has an array of students.
2. Each teacher can be part of many classes
3. Each student can be part of many classes.

Here's the schema I've built so far:

```
# Part of student.ex
schema "students" do
    field :active, :boolean, default: false
    field :birthday, :date
    field :email, :string, unique: true
    field :firstname, :string
    field :lastname, :string
    field :phone, :string, unique: true
    belongs_to :classes, Class, foreign_key: :class_id
    many_to_many :teachers, Users.Teacher, join_through: "classes"

    timestamps()
  end
```

```
# Part of teacher.ex
schema "teachers" do
    field :active, :boolean, default: false
    field :birthday, :date
    field :email, :string, unique: true
    field :firstname, :string
    field :lastname, :string
    field :phone, :string, unique: true
    belongs_to :classes, Class, foreign_key: :class_id
    many_to_many :students, Users.Student, join_through: "classes"
    timestamps()
  end
```

```
# Part of class.ex
schema "classes" do
    field :end_date, :date
    field :time, :time
    field :level, :string
    field :start_date, :date
    field :title, :string
    has_many :students, Users.Student
    has_one :teacher, Users.Teacher
    embeds_many :sessions, Session
    timestamps()
  end
```

Things look ok here. But the problem is, how do I specify "an array of student ids" in my migration file? Here are the migration functions:

```
# Part of students migration file. It's the same for teachers.
def change do
    create table(:students) do
      add :firstname, :string, null: false, size: 32
      add :lastname, :string, null: false, size: 32
      add :phone, :string, null: false, size: 16
      add :email, :string, size: 32
      add :birthday, :date
      add :active, :boolean, default: false, null: false

      timestamps()
    end

    create(unique_index(:students, [:phone]))
  end
```

This is where I'm really stuck at right now:

```
def change do
    create table(:classes) do
      add :title, :string, null: false
      add :level, :string
      add :hours, :string, null: false
      add :start_date, :date
      add :end_date, :date
      add :teacher_id, references(:teachers), primary_key: true
      # HERE! How do I create a column for an array of student_id foreign keys?
      timestamps()
    end

    create(index(:classes, [:teacher_id]))

  end
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it is stated in docs for [`Ecto.Schema.belongs_to/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Schema.html?#belongs_to/3)

> You should use `belongs_to` in the table that contains the foreign key. Imagine a `company <-> employee` relationship. If the `employee` contains the `company_id` in the underlying database table, we say the `employee` belongs to `company`.
>   In fact, when you invoke this macro, a field with the name of foreign key is automatically defined in the schema for you.

On the contrary, neither [`Ecto.Schema.has_one/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Schema.html#has_one/3) nor [`Ecto.Schema.has_many/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Schema.html#has_many/3) implies the existence of the respective field. Everything gets done by the other end of this link.

That said,

- `students` schema should have `class_id` field (already there)
- `classes` probably should have `teacher_id` (assuming a teacher might have several classes.) To do that, alter `teachers` to `has_many :classes` instead of `belongs_to :class` *and* alter `classes` to `belongs_to :teacher` instead of `has_one :teacher`.

---

Whether you want the student to belong to many classes, the schema is not correct. The existence of `class_id` foreign key in each record of `students` implies each student has this particular class associated. You should remove

```
belongs_to :classes, Class, foreign_key: :class_id
```

from `students`, because it sticks one student to one class, in the first place. Then you have to introduce `classes_to_students` join schema, as described here [`Ecto.Schema.many_to_many/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Schema.html#many_to_many/3).

Comment: Via `has_many :students, Users.Student` in the schema. Each student has `class_id`, that’s it.

Comment: Sorry I made a mistake, so I removed the comment. I meant how does this address "each student can be part of many classes?" I don't want each student to be part of only one class.

Comment: I have updated the answer. The changes in swapping `classes` and `teachers` to define who holds the reference key are still needed, I believe.

Comment: Awesome! That did it.

Comment: Can you also add about how I should reflect those changes in the migration? How do you specify `many_to_many` relation? Do I need to use `references()` for `many_to_many`, or is it just for `belongs_to`?